# Reduce space between col-lg in bootstrap in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4. Below is my html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center ">
    <div class="col-lg-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works fine on the website. However, on mobile or when I resize the browser to be very narrow, the 2 classes col-lg-6 stack on top of each other with quite a lot vertical space between them. I wonder is there any way to reduce that space?

Comment: with so little code you share, everything seems normal. Can you share more codes to show exactly the problem you're having ?

Answer (score 0):

space could be caused by either margin or padding... to set:

- padding bottom to zero, use class `pb-0`
- padding top to zero, use class `pt-0`
- margin bottom to zero, use class `mb-0`
- margin top to zero, use class `mt-0`

this is the bootstrap way... [more info here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/)